# Liferay DXP which portlet archetype to be backed by REST-Service

Tags: rest, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

With Liferay DXP a new Rest-Service archtype is provided. I successfull created a Rest-service an deployed it on my DXP.

My question is how to create/generate a portlet that uses the rest-service? Is there an archetype for a pure HTML/JS portlet? Or do i have to use and old one and modify it (how?).